# Errorlog, accesslog, slow query log, execution time log, traffic and req per sec into one tool?

Tags: mysql, php, performance, lighttpd, lamp

I'm searching for a tool designed for LAMP server that combines server Error log, Access log, slow query log, takes time of execution of PHP scripts,traffic and req per sec statistics (for example from RRDTool) and put it all into one chronological list.

Do you know this kind of tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) is a great tool for this, and free for limited processing.  However, if you're looking for a homegrown solution, I would just standardize the date format, cat them all together, and then pipe them through sort.  I.e.,

```
cat ALL_LOGS | sort on standard field
```